# Lookless Control's ItemTemplatePanel Not Able to See Dependency Property on Control

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

So when I use the below style, it is applied to my control as expected. However, the templates inside of the `GridView` (`ItemsPanelTemplate` and `ItemsTemplate`) look at the view model the consumer applies for its data context.

The problem is that I want to set the item dimensions in my control.

So my question is, how do I apply the control template as the data context to the `ItemsPanelTemplate` and the `ItemTemplate`?

My first thought was to use ancestral binding but that doesn't appear to be a feature in UWP.

My Control Class

```
public class FilterableImageWrapGrid : FilterableContentList
    {
        private GridView _partGridView;

        public Point ItemDimensions
        {
            get { return (Point)GetValue(ItemDimensionsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemDimensionsProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ItemDimensions.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemDimensionsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ItemDimensions", typeof(Point), typeof(FilterableImageWrapGrid), new PropertyMetadata(new Point()));

        public FilterableImageWrapGrid()
        {
            DefaultStyleKey = typeof(FilterableImageWrapGrid);
        }

        protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            _partGridView = GetTemplateChild("PART_FilterableImageList") as GridView;           

            base.OnApplyTemplate();
        }

        private static void OnItemDimensionsChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            FilterableImageWrapGrid wrapGrid = sender as FilterableImageWrapGrid;

            if (wrapGrid != null && wrapGrid._partGridView != null)
            {
                wrapGrid._partGridView.ItemTemplate.SetValue(GridViewItem.WidthProperty, wrapGrid.ItemDimensions.X);
                wrapGrid._partGridView.ItemTemplate.SetValue(GridViewItem.HeightProperty, wrapGrid.ItemDimensions.Y);
            }
        }
    }
```

My style in my Generic.xaml file

```
 <Style TargetType="controls:FilterableImageWrapGrid">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>                   
                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch">                        
                        <GridView                                   
                            x:Name="PART_FilterableImageList"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=FilteredItems, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=SelectedContentItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
                            <GridView.ItemContainerTransitions>
                                <TransitionCollection>
                                    <EntranceThemeTransition  IsStaggeringEnabled="True"/>
                                    <AddDeleteThemeTransition />
                                    <EdgeUIThemeTransition Edge="Left"/>
                                </TransitionCollection>
                            </GridView.ItemContainerTransitions>
                            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <ItemsWrapGrid 
                                        x:Name="PART_ItemsWrapGrid"
                                        ItemHeight="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=ItemDimensions.Y}"
                                        ItemWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=ItemDimensions.X}"
                                        Margin="2" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                   .... Data template that binds to the view model the consumer provides....
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        </GridView>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly it doesn't work to have the `RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent` binding in a template inside a template. Is that it?

then define the `ItemDimensions` property as an attached Dependency Property:

```
public class FilterableImageWrapGrid : FilterableContentList

    public static Point GetItemDimensions(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Point)obj.GetValue(ItemDimensionsProperty);
    }

    public static void SetItemDimensions(DependencyObject obj, Point value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ItemDimensionsProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemDimensionsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ItemDimensions", typeof(Point), typeof(ItemsWrapGrid), new PropertyMetadata(new Point()));

    ...
}
```

and then add this to the template:

```
                     <GridView                                   
                            x:Name="PART_FilterableImageList"
                            ...
                            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <ItemsWrapGrid 
                                        x:Name="PART_ItemsWrapGrid"                                        
                                        ItemHeight="{Binding RelativeSource=
                                 {RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=ItemDimensions.Y}"
                                        ItemWidth="{Binding RelativeSource=
                                 {RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=ItemDimensions.X}"
                                        Margin="2" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                            ...
                        </GridView>
```

That would be like an inheritable property (which don't exist in uwp (yet?)) that you manually push downward the visual tree to the inner template with the template binding.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I haven't forgotten about you. I am going to try it tonight when I get home and let you know if it works out. I kind of didn't want to create another subclass for this control. I was hoping there was a cleaner solution.

Comment: My answer was confusing before with my first idea and that edit at the end, I've edited it once more... please take a look at it now. No subclassing needed...